# verifying ubuntu hashes for 19.10

Tags: server, gnupg, hash, openpgp

I'm behind a proxy, and dirmngr doesn't seem to honour the http_proxy rules. So i'm doing these steps

1. download sha256sums.gpg and sha256sums from ubuntuhashes
2. gpg --verify sha256sums.gpg sha256sums
3. The key doesn't exist in my keyring, so i go to the pool.sks-keyservers.net and search for the key 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092. The results: 
   http://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371/pks/lookup?search=0xD94AA3F0EFE21092&op=vindex
4. the site returns a page with a set of keys and keyIDs. I select the key that resembles 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092 and copy this pgp key block into a file
5. gpg --import  returns an invalid packet, read block error.

How do i resolve this error? On my system the apt-key list shows a similar signing key, so importing this from the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg, i'm able to verify the ubuntu hashes. On the other hand, verifying a file with a key that is distributed with the release doesn't make sense. Using the pgp key that is returned from the sks-keyservers should be the preferred method.

Also, the web search on pool.sks-servers.net returns a page that is not https by default. Is it de rigeur to return results to keys using http?

Comment: Just to add, the pgp keyblocks obtained through any of these methods, through direct website search, through multiple keyserver searches, hkp server download, from CD rom isos, should contain valid content that can be imported into a local user keyring.